# How to save console output in python in excel in real time

Tags: python, excel, database

I want to save the output in the console log from our object detection and save it in excel and automatically update the excel in real-time, each time that the console log is outputting results, or can you suggest a better way to save the output in real-time other than excel is greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: Unclear what you are asking but presumably write directly to excel and not the console?

Comment: python has function to save files .xlsx but it doesn't have functions to control running Excel. And this would need in Excel to open (probably) menu `File` and select `Reload file`. The only idea is to use module `keyboard`, `pynput` or `pyautogui` to send keys to system and it can send them to active window - if Excel will be active then it may get these keys - and this way you can use keys to execute function in Excel. You may also see if module `win32` has method to control Windows program.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.